# Using sed to obtain pattern range through multiple files in a directory

Tags: linux, bash

I was wondering if it was possible to use the sed command to find a range between 2 patterns (in this case, dates) and output these lines in the range to a new file.

Right now, I am just looking at one file and getting lines within my time range of the file FileMoverTransfer.log. However, after a certain time period, these logs are moved to new log files with a suffix such as FileMoverTransfer.log-20180404-xxxxxx.gz. Here is my current code:

`sed -n '/^'$start_date'/,/^'$end_date'/p;/^'$end_date'/q' FileMoverTransfer.log >> /public/FileMoverRoot/logs/intervalFMT.log`

While this doesn't work, as sed isn't able to look through all of the files in the directory starting with FileMoverTransfer.log?

```
sed -n '/^'$start_date'/,/^'$end_date'/p;/^'$end_date'/q' FileMoverTransfer.log* >> /public/FileMoverRoot/logs/intervalFMT.log
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The `q` command exits `sed` completely, not just the current file.

Comment: If the other files end in `.gz` they are probably compressed, and `sed` doesn’t uncompress them before looking for the given regexps.

Comment: Would an `awk` solution be acceptable, or are you stuck with `sed`?

Comment: I am not limited to using sed, I'd be open to using awk

Answer (score 1):

The range operator only operates within a single file, so you can't use it if the start is in one file and the end is in another file.

You can use `cat` to concatenate all the files, and pipe this to `sed`:

```
cat FileMoverTransfer.log* | sed -n "/^$start_date/,/^$end_date/p;/^$end_date/q" >> /public/FileMoverRoot/logs/intervalFMT.log
```

And instead of quoting and unquoting the `sed` command, you can use double quotes so that the variables will be expanded inside it. This will also prevent problems if the variables contain whitespace.

Comment: I guess the problem that I'm running into is that the next file may not necessarily contain the start or end date, but still be within the range. Not sure how to make that work. Maybe sed isn't the right command to use?

Comment: Use `cat` to concatenate all the files and pipe that to `sed`.

Comment: cat will output binary stuff for gz files, won't work.

Comment: I am able to unzip the .gz files first, so that isn't a problem. I believe using cat and piping into the sed command should work

Comment: @Jake `sed` can't process gz files directly, either. There's nothing in the question about needing to decompress files.

Comment: You can use `gzcat` instead of `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

**awk solution**

As the OP confirmed that an `awk` solution would be acceptable, I post it.

```
(gunzip -c FileMoverTransfer.log-*.gz; cat FileMoverTransfer.log ) \
  |awk -v st="$start_date" -v en="$end_date" '$1>=st&&$1<=en{print;next}$1>en{exit}'\
  >/public/FileMoverRoot/logs/intervalFMT.log
```

This solution is functionally almost identical to Barmar’s `sed` solution, with the difference that his solution, like the OP’s, will print and quit at the first record matching the end date, while mine will print all lines matching the end date and quit at the first record past the end date, without printing it.

Some remarks:

- The OP didn't specify the date format. I suppose it is a format compatible with ordinary string order, otherwise some conversion function should be used.
- The files `FileMoverTransfer.log-*.gz` must be named in such a way that their alphabetical ordering corresponds to the chronological order (which is probably the case.)
- I suppose that the dates are separated from the rest of the line by whitespace. If they aren’t, you have to supply the `-F` option to `awk`. E.g., if the dates are separated by `-`, you must write `awk -F- ...`
- `awk` is much faster than `sed` in this case, because `awk` simply looks for the separator (whitespace or whatever was supplied with `-F`) while `sed` performs a regexp match.
- There is no concept of *range* in my code, only date comparison. The only place where I suppose that the lines are ordered is when I say `$1>en{exit}`, that is *exit when a line is newer than the end date.* If you remove that final pattern and its action, the code will run through the whole input, but you could drop the requirement that the files be ordered.